# Switch statement - comparing zero value

Tags: reporting-services

I currently have two text box. One is to display the first value in my column called principal. The second textbox is to display a text, if the value is equal to zero, display "The principal is zero" else display "The Principal value is not zero". X being the principal amount.

The first textbox populates fine using

```
=First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO")
```

The second textbox produces #Error using

```
=Switch(First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO") = 0, "The Principal is zero", "The Principal is not zero")
```

First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO") Produces 100000.

May I ask how do I fix my switch statement so it stops displaying #Erorr

Comment: Is there a particular reason you went with SWITCH instead of IIF?

Comment: @EricHauenstein,  no there's no particular reason.

Comment: Do you still receive an error if you use IIF with this same syntax?

Comment: Hi @EricHauenstein interesting, that worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using is correct for the IIF operator.  Since you are only doing one comparison use that instead and it should work.

Edit: In response to your comment, If you want the false part of the expression to show the actual value, you would do the following:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO") = 0, "The Principal is zero", "The Principal is "+ CStr(First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO")))
```

However, you could just get rid of the IIF statement altogether and make the expression:

```
"The Principal is "+ CStr(First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO"))
```

And always show the value of PaymentInfoDTO.

Comment: Hi Eric just to add ontop of question, how would I display the value within the false statement. For example I would like the prompt to maybe say "The principal is 100000"

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a switch statement there. Given the structure of your expression it would be best suited as an IIF()

=IIF(condition to evaluate, result if true, result if false)

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO") = 0, "The Principal is zero", "The Principal is not zero")
```

A switch statement on the other hand only returns one result per condition checked.

=switch(condition,result if true, condition2, result if 2 is true)

You could reformat your expression to use a switch by doing this.

```
=Switch(First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO") = 0, "The Principal is zero", 
First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO") <> 0, "The Principal is not zero")
```

Switch statements are generally best used when you have a number of values to evaluate individually. Not really the best for simple boolean returns such as checking if something is equal to 0 or not.

Comment: I think that in second expression second condition must be this: `First(Fields!Principal.Value, "PaymentInfoDTO") <> 0`

Comment: you are absolutely correct let me edit that really quick